# IOS subscription end notification

Tags: ios, ios4, voip, subscription, auto-renewing

I am looking to build a ios application that will use an auto-renewable subscription on a monthly biases. We will be using some VOIP features that we will be charged monthly for. My question is, how can we be notified when a user cancels a subscription in IOS, so that we can cancel the users VOIP telephone number with our provider.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will need to verify the receipt the same way you do for regular In App Purchases, but obviously you will do this every time the subscription period expires. Check out the documentation on this, [Verifying an Auto-renewable Subscription Receipt](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/RenewableSubscriptions/RenewableSubscriptions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH4-SW5)

So based on this, it appears you will need to setup your server to check for a valid subscription every month (cron job?). This will allow you to cancel the VOIP number in your system if the subscription is no longer valid. Your app would be responsible for verifying a subscription is still valid when it is opened or the user attempts to access features that require a subscription.

**Updated For Comment**

The sandbox is supposed to return expiration dates in the following scheme.

[image]

This is from page 164 of the [iTunes Connect Developer Guide](https://itunesconnect.apple.com/docs/iTunesConnect_DeveloperGuide.pdf)

If it is not working this way you may want to file a bug report.

Comment: (First time) Immediately after purchasing subscription, i'm requested for verification receipt. In the receipt received, there's "expires_date" field which gives time in milliseconds since 1970. When testing with sandbox server, its always giving today's date. I don't know whether sandbox server gives only short duration for testing purpose or will it give exact expires-duration only for renewed subscriptions. How can I check the expired date.

Comment: Check my update, actually I just noticed I answered [the question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8739116/ios-getting-expiration-time-of-in-app-subscription-purchases/) you posted with the same information.

Answer (score 0):

Also, please not the following from Apples IAP doc:

Additionally, a sandbox subscription will only autorenew a maximum of 6 times.  After the subscription has auto-renewed 6 times, it will no longer renew in the sandbox.