# iPhone In-app purchase Auto-renewable

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase

When i try to buy a product for first time from iphone sandbox environment (i.e product com.abc) then i m able to get the proper response, and if i try to buy this product again then   the transaction failed method is called, i dont know what to do.
And when i try to restore the product(i.e com.abc), a restore method is called multiple times, and when i print the product id then i m getting 5 to 6 times of printing of product id (i.e com.abc) that means 5 to 6 times my restore method is called.
If anybody have the solution of above 2 problems then please help me.
Thanks In Advance

**NOTE: com.abc product is auto-renewable.**

Answer (score 0):

here is actually how much time period you keep(1 year or 6months) based on the time period your subscription is valid 
 if you keep 1 year the subscription is valid up to 1hour and [verify this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8648024/ios-subscription-end-notification) after one hour you will get the normal transaction